# Plotting Probability Density Function with Z scores on pandas/python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

with this code :

```
df1 = (df.ix[:,1:] - df.ix[:,1:].mean()) / df.ix[:,1:].std()
```

I calculated z scores on one column with frequency distribution of items from my grouped dataframe on the second column. Now the result looked something like this :

```
Z Score     Frequency Distribution
-2.394214       1
-2.280489       1
-2.166763       2
-2.109900       7
-2.053037       4
-1.939311       7
-1.882448      11
-1.825586       9
-1.768723       7
-1.711860       4
-1.654997      11 ..about 73 items
```

Now i wanted to create a probability density plot with z scores on my x-axis and density of frequency on y-axis. So I decided to try on a bar chart first to see how the results turn out . The bar chart showed something like this:

[image]

with this code : `ax1 = counts1.plot(kind='bar',stacked = False)`, so I thought let's see how probability density function would look like where I changed bar to 'kde' and got something like this:

[image]

I suppose the plot is okay but I am not really satisfied with my x-axis. Is it possible to index each z scores on x-axis (lets say like x-axis of my bar plot) ? I am new to pandas/matplotlib/ and I am trying to learn plotting, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I believe you're not doing it correctly, can you post a sample of your initial data (or something leveraging np.random or something, anything we can use to load data) please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Preparing a dummy data:*

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

np.random.seed([314, 42])
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(ZScore=np.sort(np.random.uniform(-2, 2, 50)), 
                       FreqDist=np.random.randint(1, 30, 50)))
df.head()
```

[image]

*Plotting:*

```
ax = df.plot(x='ZScore', y='FreqDist', kind='kde', figsize=(10, 6))
# get the x axis values corresponding to this slice (See beneath the plot)
arr = ax.get_children()[0]._x
# take the first and last element of this array to constitute the xticks and 
# also rotate the ticklabels to avoid overlapping
plt.xticks(np.linspace(arr[0], arr[-1]), rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Output of the `list` of child artists obtained after plot:

```
ax.get_children()
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x1d68b5c6d68>, <--- first element in list of child artists
 <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x1d6895f14a8>,
 <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x1d6895f1f98>,
 <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x1d68d881828>,
 <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x1d68b995048>,
 <matplotlib.axis.XAxis at 0x1d689aeb978>,
 <matplotlib.axis.YAxis at 0x1d68d7ff908>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x1d689b55cf8>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x1d689b55a20>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x1d689b55c88>,
 <matplotlib.legend.Legend at 0x1d687645390>,
 <matplotlib.patches.Rectangle at 0x1d689b55080>]
```

Comment: Thank you Nickil. It is such a marvellous answer.