# Is there a function that can be used to plot z-score distribution in python?

Tags: python, statistics, probability-distribution

I have a dataset for which I have chosen one variable with a normal distribution. I calculated the sample mean and standard deviation for this variable. Next, I calculated the z-scores.

Now I have a list of z-score that I would like to plot to see the z-score distribution. ( do have an idea it will resemble the raw distribution). Is there a function in Python that can help me plot it by passing the z-scores, mean, and standard deviation?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41123500/plotting-probability-density-function-with-z-scores-on-pandas-python

Comment: @ymmx this post was not very helpful as I have no idea if they grouped the data first and then calculated the z-score?

Comment: You should give a minimal example to start with